# user_data in local storage used in ajax call automatically

Tags: php, ajax, local-storage

I am trying to figure out how a particular ecommerce website works. When I type the url as

```
"www.example.com/api/followstore?store=abc"
```

the result is:

(when user is logged in)

```
{"error":"","success":true,"followedstoreId":1042,"data":[1122,566,1042]}
```

(when user is not logged in)

```
{"error":"not logged in","success":false}
```

So it is basically doing a ajax call with store="abc".

My question is from where is it getting the user_data(information that user is logged in or not and lot of other user specific data) which is saved in the local storage(not as cookie or session storage) since I am not passing it in URI.

As per my knowledge any variable stored in local storage cannot be accessed in php directly and need to be 'post' or 'get'.

So how is this particular URI working.

Comment: how are you sure its not using cookies? you don't have to pass that data in through a uri explicitly. just like when you are logged onto facebook, you can just type in facebook.com and it will respond based on your cookies. cookies are associated with domains...i'm guessing this is done through a cookie.

Comment: @gabereal  I can see all the user data being stored in local storage(for example user_id, user_name, followed_store, cart_items). Plus i dont see any cookies also containing that kind of data.

Comment: when logged in, do you see any cookies associated with the domain? check the domain property of the cookies.